# LINUX: Permissions for files: Identify if it is a file or directory, and its access allowed to the world, user, and group

Tags: permissions, files

I am having trouble understanding permissions for directories and files in LINUX.

By examining permissions for each of the following files, identify if it is a file or directory, and describe the access allowed to the world, user, and group:

- a. -rwx---r-x
- b. drwx------
- c. -rwxrwxr--
- d. dr-x---r-x
- e. -rwx---rwx

Answer (score 4):

The permissions in the bit patterns you gave in your question are broken down as follows:

#### example #1

[image: ss of permissions #1]

#### example #2

[image: ss of permissions #2]

The bits are broken down thusly:

```
-                            rw-            ---              ---
^-- denotes a directory      ^-- user bits  ^-- group bits   ^-- other bits
```

Each pack of bits (user, group, other) contain 3 values.

- r = read
- w = write
- x = executable

So a grouping of `-rw-rw-r--` means it's a file with user & group read/write permissions, and other users have only read access. A  grouping of `drwxr-x-r-x` means that it's a directory, and that the owner/user has read/write/execute permissions on the directory, and the group and others have only read and execute permissions.

#### Remember

The owner of a file/directory is the username listed in the 3rd column of `ls -l` output. The group that's associated to a file/directory is the 4th column, again a group called `root`. The Set of other users is basically anyone that doesn't fall into either of the first two categories (i.e. not the user root, not the group root).

```
$ ls
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     1749 Apr 14  2005 b
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     4096 Dec 19 22:48 bin
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     4096 Apr 10  2005 Desktop
```

#### Note on permissions bits

For simplicity sake I'm ignoring that there are in fact more potential bits than the standard r, w, and x. See the [chmod wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod) for more details.

#### References

- [Chapter 25: UNIX File Attributes & Access Permissions](http://docweb.cns.ufl.edu/docs/d0107/ar07s09.html)
- [UNIX, LINUX & OS X File Permissions](http://www.comentum.com/unix-osx-permissions.html)